# Почему форма работает только в FF

Tags: html

```
<form action="loadfile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input id="load" name="load" type="file" size="59">
<input id="descrip" name="descrip" type="text" size="70.9">
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

loadfile.php

```
 <?
    $des = $_POST['descrip'];
    if (empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])) die('Файл не принят сервером');
    $tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $fname = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'file/image/'.$fname)) die('Не удалось переместить файл из временной папки');
    echo '<img src="/file/image/'.$fname.'" /><br />'.$des; // картинка загружена
    $fp = fopen ($fname.".txt", "w"); 
    fwrite($fp,$des);
    fclose($fp); 
    ?>
```

Почему данная ниже форма работает только в FireFox, а в Opera и IE - нет, при нажатии "Отправить" ничего не происходит, как будто этого скрипта и нет.  Беспощадно гуглил, но практически ничего не нашел, были похожие темы, но не то.

Comment: Проверьте настройки своего сервера, и перенаправления на файл action="loadfile.php" попробуйте вариант с GET переменными.

Comment: А зачем size такой странный? + инпут зовется load, а проверяется img. Это не по теме, но проверьте, мб глючит где-то здесь.

Comment: Импут я переименовал, все равно робит только в FF.

Comment: Попробовать: в action прописать путь от корня (типа "/admin/loadfile.php"); убрать все-таки дробный size; проверить наличие на странице левого javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробуем так

```
<form action="loadfile.php" name="Loadimage" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="GET">
<input id="load" name="img" type="file" size="60">
<input id="descrip" name="descrip" type="text" size="71">
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Тут проблем нет, если индикатор не относится к javascript или jquary.

Comment: Спасибо!Как всегда Node_pro помог.